# mongodb haskell driver installation

Tags: mongodb, haskell

I've been experimenting with mongodb and haskell. I installed the haskell driver for mongodb per https://github.com/srp/mongoDB/blob/master/tutorial.md. I took the "From Hackage using cabal" route and everything seems to build successfully. I start the haskell repl, ghci, and do...

import Data.MongoDB

and get...

Could not find module `Data.MongoDB'

Has anyone seen this problem before? Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 4):

You want the line

```
import Database.MongoDB
```

instead of

```
import Data.MongoDB
```

Comment: Oops! "import Database.MongoDB" works but then I trycon <- connect "127.0.0.1" []

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm having a problem connecting. con <- connect "127.0.0.1" [] says "The function `connect' is applied to two arguments,..."